# mySQL password policy refuses all attempts to create user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

My current installation of mySQL/phpMyAdmin on my ubuntu server is refusing to allow any user to be created with any password I have tried. The error is always:

`ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements`

I have never had this error before with other installations of mysql, on server and xampp/localhost both. This is a new server installation however.

For example, on the mysql terminal on the command line, any attempt to create a user (with extremely random passwords) fails

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'ses'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yIO8v3hVai0zosaD';
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
mysql> CREATE USER 'ses'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yIO8v3hVai0zosaDyIO8v3hVai0zosaDyIO8v3hVai0zosaD';
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

Same thing with phpMyAdmin

[image]

[image]

With the following error at the bottom

```
Warning in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#261
 mysqli_query(): (HY000/1819): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Backtrace

./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#261: mysqli_query(
object,
string 'SELECT PASSWORD(\'rSxYcnCcO2fhhKgD\') AS `password`;',
integer 0,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#244: PMA_DBI_Mysqli->realQuery(
string 'SELECT PASSWORD(\'rSxYcnCcO2fhhKgD\') AS `password`;',
object,
integer 1,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#1944: PMA_DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(
string 'SELECT PASSWORD(\'rSxYcnCcO2fhhKgD\') AS `password`;',
object,
integer 1,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/server_privileges.lib.php#5055: PMA_DatabaseInterface->fetchSingleRow(string 'SELECT PASSWORD(\'rSxYcnCcO2fhhKgD\') AS `password`;')
./libraries/server_privileges.lib.php#5179: PMA_getHashedPassword(string 'rSxYcnCcO2fhhKgD')
./libraries/server_privileges.lib.php#4176: PMA_getSqlQueriesForDisplayAndAddUser(
string 'test-accountdb',
string '%',
string '',
)
./server_privileges.php#167: PMA_addUser(
NULL,
string 'test-accountdb',
string '%',
NULL,
boolean true,
)
```

Edit: Added results for the mysql `validate_password%` variables

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password_dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password_length             | 8      |
| validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password_number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password_policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password_special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: If you run this command what do you see? `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added the results for validate password. I had checked this before, but it didnt seem out of the ordinary.

Comment: Ya the passwords you've tried look like they'd be allowed according to those values. Is there anything referencing `validate_password` in your my.ini file?

Comment: I take that back. This password, `yIO8v3hVai0zosaDyIO8v3hVai0zosaDyIO8v3hVai0zosaD` doesn't contain a special character. Try adding a `$` or `*` to one of your passwords.

Comment: Great, good catch that did work. I was using the phpMyAdmin Generate button, and it never generated special chars. Sometimes it didnt generate a number either, so I just made sure they were each in there. If you make this an answer, I will accept. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. I have a feeling the PMA team will sort this out eventually, but it can't hurt to submit a feature request if you're up for it. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the [Validate Password Plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/validate-password-plugin.html) at work. It was introduced in MySQL 5.6.6.

According to the values returned from the `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';` you're missing a single special character in your password as indicated by `validate_password_special_char_count | 1`.

Add a special character such as `$` or `*` to this password `yIO8v3hVai0zosaD` you'll be able to create the user.

Comment: Thanks again, ill add a ticket. I didn't really think to even check much into the password requirements because I was using that button. Another lesson to not assume things in computing, I should know better.

Answer (score 5):

**Procedure 1:**

Step1: Log in with root user ane and password

Step2: run bellow command in Sql terminal

```
 uninstall plugin validate_password
```

Step3 : create a new user with whatever password you want

Step4: run bellow command in Sql  terminal

```
INSTALL PLUGIN validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so';
```

Step5: Checkout now your username & password by login

**Procedure 2:**

Add a special character such as $ or * to this password icluding other cases    like digit,small case character, uper case character